# Why is my Mongoose query within a loop only returning the first result?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have been struggling with this for days now. I am trying to return the data that is referenced by a list of IDs.

Example JSON of one team:

```
 {  
   "Name":"Team 3",
   "CaptainID":"57611e3431c360f822000003",
   "CaptainName":"Name",
   "DateCreated":"2016-06-20T10:14:36.873Z",
   "Members":[  
      "57611e3431c360f822000003", //Same as CaptainID
      "57611e3431c360f822000004" //Other members
   ]
}
```

Here is the route:

```
router.route('/teams/:user_id')
.get(function (req, res) {

    TeamProfile.find({
        Members : {
            $in : [req.params.user_id]
        }
    }).exec(function (err, teamProfiles) {

        teamProfiles.forEach(function (teamProfile) {

            UserProfile.find({
                UserID : {
                    $in : teamProfile.Members.map(function (id) {
                        return id;
                    })
                }
            }, function (err, userProfiles) {           
                teamProfile.Members = userProfiles;
                console.log(teamProfile); //will console log the remaining 2
            })
            .exec(function (err) {              
                res.json(teamProfile) //returns the first one only
            })
        })
    });
})
```

The idea is for the route to return the profiles just by using the IDs to fetch the up-to-date data.

However, it is working to a point. It gets the user information and all but it doesn't return all the Teams + all the users as commented in the code. There are 3 teams in total. Only the first one is returned. If I remove `res.json(teamProfile)` it console logs all 3 teams. I want to return all 3 teams.

Comment: Use async function to obtain result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your response is being called before completing all db operations. So instead of for each use async.forEach function. Install async module

```
var  async = require('async');
router.route('/teams/:user_id').get(function (req, res) {

TeamProfile.find({
    Members : {
        $in : [req.params.user_id]
    }
}).exec(function (err, teamProfiles) {

    async.forEach(teamProfiles,function (teamProfile,cb) {

        UserProfile.find({
            UserID : {
                $in : teamProfile.Members.map(function (id) {
                    return id;
                })
            }
        }, function (err, userProfiles) {           
            teamProfile.Members = userProfiles;
            cb() // Callback
        })

    },function(){
       res.json(teamProfiles) 
    })
});
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it has something to do with it completing all operations. There's a small typo in your answer. It's _res.json(teamProfiles)_. Made my day! :)